# ClassCastException while running Flink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am getting below error while running Flink with flink-connector-kafka-0.9 
    connector .

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaProducer cannot be cast to org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction
at com.dataartisans.ReadFromKafka.main(ReadFromKafka.java:57)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Initially I was able to fetch records from Kafka . But now getting the above error .
```

Answer (score 1):

A `FlinkKafkaProducer08` is not a source function but a sink function. The producer has the task to emit elements to Kafka. In contrast to that, the `FlinkKafkaConsumer08` is the source function which reads data from Kafka.